# Automatic wiki if I answer my own question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, community-wiki

I [asked a question a few weeks back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627234/pattern-for-associating-pyparsing-results-with-a-linked-list-of-nodes) and didn't get a good answer... I wound up answering it myself.

My answer was immediately converted to a [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627234/pattern-for-associating-pyparsing-results-with-a-linked-list-of-nodes/5818078#5818078).  I also got a robot captcha for the first time.

Is the wiki conversion and captcha expected, or did I accidentally trip a wire?

Comment: The wire you tripped was editing your question too many times. I don't know exactly what the magic number is, but it looks like with your 12th edit, you hit it.

Comment: The captcha and wiki are two different things, you just happened to get them both in the same time by chance.. Chris explained both pretty well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question had converted to CW (as a result of your last edit on the 12<sup>th</sup> April) so all answers posted after that point will be CW.

Re the captcha - I've found that if I paste a post into the text box (rather than typing it out again) I *always* trigger the captcha regardless of my rep on the site. So if you were "too quick" in hitting the "post" button after starting the answer then that would be the reason.

Comment: thanks... any thoughts about the robot captcha

Comment: Well, the robot captcha picture is quite entertaining. I've hit it twice recently, but I think both times I'd answered twice; it may well be that 2 posts on the same thread cause it (e.g. Q&A or 2 answers).

Comment: Just got one where I changed my mind about commenting and cut/pasted the comment into an answer without having posted the comment.

VERY ANNOYING - since it happens often and always when I am the first to comment. That invariably makes my answer later than others by at least 30 seconds :(

I am not amused when that happens