# Why does SO think I'm a bot?

Tags: support, captcha

Lately I've been getting CAPTCHAs almost every time I post an answer. Is there any particular behavior that makes SO trigger the bot test so often?

**EDIT**: It just occurred to me that most of these CATPCHAs have been occurring just after experiencing [missing previews due to this Chrome 11 issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89224/does-anyone-have-problems-viewing-so-in-chrome-11). I guess downloading a page, but not the JavaScript might be considered bot-like behavior, so these issues might be connected. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Maybe one of the things listed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear)?

Comment: When `sstatic.net` is used, no cookies are sent. Hence SE won't know you're not downloading the JavaScript.

Comment: Because you are a bot.  Admit it.  Come out of the ... server closet?  Forgive me, I don't know what kind of closets you bots hang in.

Answer (score 5):

Certain user behavior like [pasting answers in quickly can trigger captchas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89110/automatic-wiki-if-i-answer-my-own-question/89111#89111).  There are probably other criteria that trigger them as well.