# Why do I keep getting accused of trying to pass the Turing Test?

Tags: support, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How often do captchas appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear)
>   [Why does SO think I'm a bot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90352/why-does-so-think-im-a-bot)
>   [Please tone the captchas back down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110905/please-tone-the-captchas-back-down)

I have very frequently been presented with the captcha page over the past few months. Since I have a reasonably robust history of participation on StackExchange sites, I'd think it were self-evident that I'm not a bot.

Why do I keep getting hit with the captcha?

**EDIT:** In the process of asking this very question no less! Post and then, bam, captcha!

Comment: You mean accused of *failing* the Turing Test?  *Passing* would mean you *do* seem human.

Comment: I think my thinking was that I'd have to pass the Turing Test to be able to post an answer. Or something. I'm just going to change it.

Comment: Jon Skeet submitted an SQL injection, changing the code and presenting all other users with CAPTCHAs, thus slowing us down and protecting his rep lead.  Obviously.

Comment: Thanks to the mods for pointing out the duplicates that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the test comes up when you make a lot of edits very quickly -- I imagine there is some heuristic which triggers the test.

Comment: I just got hit with a Turing Test while posting an answer.  Lots of pre-post editing though.